# Sum of column per distinct ID and group by different column

Tags: postgresql, query

Let's say I have the following table:

```
create table orders (id int, order_id int, vendor varchar, price int, quantity int);

INSERT INTO orders values 
(1, 1, 'nike', 10, 2),
(2, 2, 'nike', 10, 3),
(3, 3, 'adidas', 15, 1),
(4, 3, 'adidas', 15, 5);
```

I want to get the sum of the price per distinct order_id and total sum of the quantity grouped by vendor. So the answer here would be:

```
| vendor | sum_price | sum_quantity |
|  nike  | 20        |      5       |
| adidas | 15        |      6       |
```

Notice how the sum of the price for 'adidas' is only 15, because they both have the same order_id, so it'll only take one. In all cases, the one to choose whenever multiple order_id's are the same doesn't matter because it will always be associated with the same price.
Is it also possible to do this without a nested query?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense! You could do `SELECT o.vendor, SUM(o.price)
FROM orders o
GROUP BY o.vendor
ORDER BY o.vendor DESC;` - result vendor sum
nike 20
adidas 30
, but you don't appear to want that! Why is your desired result for adidas not 30?

Comment: @Vérace I only want to sum one price per order_id as I had said in the OP. So since the records with ID 3 and 4 both have order_id of `3`, it would only grab one of them

Comment: But you have **3** orders, therefore you will get 3 records in your resultset? I don't understand why/how you can have 1 order (i.e. order_id 3) with two order_lines (id = 3,4) with the same vendor and price - it **appears to me** that we're not getting the full picture? If you have an order_id field, why have a further id field for the orders table?

Comment: @Vérace this is a simplified dataset. I understand the logic of the table doesn't make too much sense but i've oversimplified for the sake of this post.

Comment: What if the order with id = 4 had a different price than the one with id = 3?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that would never be the case in my scenario. If you want, we can just assume that it'd choose max value